# Installing Gazebo 8 on Windows 7 with Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7-x64

(I follow this tutoriel: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_on_windows&cat=install)

I try to install Gazebo 8 on windows 7 with Visual studio 2017, but whenever I use the command '..\configure' (step 10) I have this error:

> -- Enable upstream CFlags
>
> CMake Error at cmake/DefaultCFlags.cmake:64 (message):
>
> Gazebo requires VS 2013 or greater.

I don't know if it's due to my version of visual studio (but I assume that 2017 is a greater version than 2013).

So what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, in the file DefaultCFlags.cmake there is this line (line 63):

> if (NOT MSVC12)

So you need to use visual studio 12 (2013).
(or you can change this line, for me it was `if (NOT MSVC14)`, I don't really know if it will cause some problems later but it work)